# UI Testing failure - No matches found for SearchField

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

My XCode recorded UI test fails on the second line:

```
XCUIElement *musicselectviewNavigationBar = app.navigationBars[@"MusicSelectView"];
[[musicselectviewNavigationBar.otherElements childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeSearchField].element tap];
[[musicselectviewNavigationBar.searchFields containingType:XCUIElementTypeButton identifier:@"Clear text"].element typeText:@"Lean"];
```

Upon testing I get this error:

```
UI Testing failure - No matches found for "MusicSelectView" NavigationBar
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Access the search bar directly instead of using the recorded path.

```
[app.searchFields[@"Clear text"] tap];
[app.searchFields[@"Clear text"] typeText:@"Lean"];
```

If there is only one search field present, you can access it with `element`.

```
[[app.searchFields element] tap];
[[app.searchFields element] typeText:@"Lean"];
```

Comment: Your second suggestions works. Thanks for that. I modified my question slightly. It's the second line that fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. check what you have at line 1 in `app.navigationBars`
2. set your navigation bar accessibilityIdentifier to @"MusicSelectView"
3. access your navigation bar with `matchingIdentifier:@"MusicSelectView"` method call